# AutoMapper - Create one mapping for all generic class usages

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, automapper

I have an `OverridableValue<T>` class to represent a value that can be manually overriden (Contains a `T Value` prop and a boolean for whether it's manual or not). This class is in use in my internal model, and in my API I have a DTO that should just hold the value without consideration for if it's manual or not.
So for example let's say I use these classes:

```
public class Test
{
    public OverridableValue<string> Prop1 { get; set; }
    public OverridableValue<int> Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestDTO
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use the AutoMapper to create a mapping between the Test class and the TestDTO class. I can do this:

```
CreateMap<OverridableValue<string>, string>().ConvertUsing(o => o.Value);
CreateMap<OverridableValue<int>, int>().ConvertUsing(o => o.Value);
CreateMap<Test, TestDTO>();
```

and this will work, but I don't want to add a line for each possible generic usage of the OverridableValue class. I was wondering if there is way to create a single mapping for every single usage. Basically, I want something like this:

```
CreateMap<OverridableValue<T>, T>().ConvertUsing(o => o.Value);
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: You can add an conversion operator to `T` in `OverridableValue` and AM will use that, no converter needed.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Worked almost perfectly. It did the trick for all types except for sting for some reason, which instead of getting the string cvalue it seems to do a "ToString" and then puts the type name in the DTO instead of the value. Any idea why?

Comment: Solved it by overriding the ToString method, but still feels like a weird behavior so if you have any idea on how to make it not use the ToString it'd be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@LucianBargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) for the answer:
Instead of adding a mapping line for each possible type, the solution was to add an implicit conversion in the `OverridableValue<T>` class:

```
public static implicit operator T(OverridableValue<T> overridableValue) => overridableValue.Value;
```

That worked for 99% of the cases. The only issue after that was specifically in converting `OverridableValue<string>` to a `string`. In this case the AutoMapper decided to use the class's `ToString()` method instead of doing an implicit conversion. So to fix this I also overridden the ToString method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: There is a `Mappers` list you can change to remove [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/MapperRegistry.cs#L10), but a map to `string` would also work.